# jQuery UI - Using a different icon css with .button()

Tags: css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, css-sprites

Wondering if anyone knows a way to combat this shortcoming.

I use jQuery UI buttons for all of my button actions and the stock icons are a tad boring and I much prefer using an icon set from the twitter bootstrap.

before I go any further here is how I'm styling the buttons:

```
$('#juiBtnLocked').button({
    disabled: true,
    icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-locked"
    }
});
```

it seems that the icons property only accepts jquery ui css styles, which I don't know why that should matter as the value provided is the full css name from the css file so logically it should *technically* accept ANY css rule given.

my question is, has anyone successfully got another css sprite code to work with the buttons?

to answer the question on why I don't just use the twitter buttons, its because that's breaking the jquery ui buttons and I use too much of the jquery ui toolkit to ditch it. If twitters dialog was more robust, I'd skim the jquery ui a bit, but its too limited for my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply override the styling for that class using CSS.

```
.ui-icon-locked {
    background: url(myimage.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

`ui-icon-locked` is not a CSS rule. It is just a hook for a HTML class. The default rules for the styles (including the icons) are stored in `jquery-ui.css` in the directory of the theme you are using.

For example, in the [`jquery-ui.css` of the base theme of 1.9.1](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css) you can find these:

```
.ui-icon { width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png)/*{iconsContent}*/; }
...
.ui-icon-locked { background-position: -192px -96px; }
```

Comment: there's more sprites on the twitter bootstrap than on the jquery ui set. but it seems to be the way to resolve this.

Comment: Just created an [experimental demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LdHbh/) - lacks the default jQuery UI theme, but it still shows what happens.

Answer (score 0):

what bažmegakapa said is a good answer, which is why I marked it as the answer, but I found another way to do it that allows me both usages. I'm writing it here so people know another way to do it.

with twitter bootstrap, you have button CSS and then you have button js code that's similar to that of jquery ui.

all I did was took out the js code from their buttons and just use the css rules to style my buttons. now jquery ui is happy and so am I.

I noticed this same approach will work on a few other things within the twitter bootstrap.

This actually was a better solution than how I was doing it as its now all html controlled compared to making a button element and using jquery ui to style and mold it, which is a bit overkill I suppose.